# Suddenly can not upload images

Tags: file-uploads, error, image

I suddenly can not upload images and get the following error (Even though all is writeable)

I tried to upload files that i had previously uploaded to make sure they are not damaged and still get the same error

What else could i check to make sure all is correct?

ExpressionEngine v2.5.5

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file

Filename: libraries/Image_lib.php

Line Number: 1246
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: '/home/*/public_html/cms/images/uploads/general/656.jpg' is not a valid JPEG file

Filename: libraries/Image_lib.php

Line Number: 1246
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/*/public_html/cms/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 408
Thumbnail could not be created for the image. Please make sure the thumbnail directory is writable.

Upload to general   

Upload File
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the images are actually of the type uploaded.  The error is suggesting they're not valid JPEGs, so it's worth checking they've not been saved as, say, a PNG file and renamed to JPEG.

Alternatively, the file could be corrupt either at your or the server end.  Finally, if part of the file has been written it's possible the disk is full at the server end, leading to a premature end of file.